# Is there a way to get previous radio value in "click" or "change" event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, checked

I need to know if user clicked to already checked radio or he made a new choice.
Now I detect it via "focus", "click" and "change" events combination (store old value in "focus", and compare it with current in "click" or "change" to detect and handle click to already checked radio).

Just to clarify: I cant store previous state in click handler, because I could not get the the initial state here; or "focus+click" or "load+(prev)click+click";

But it looks like a hack for me, and I assume that there is **a more straight way** to do this using built-in jquery features, **using just one event handler**. 
Is there something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If using single event handler is a must as you mention, why not use only mousedown? Check if it's 'checked' that's the previous value. For the radio, the new value will be also 'checked'. For the checkbox, the new value will be the opposite of the old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mousedown` as @Bukent Vural suggests.

Get the current value before change with `$('input[name=test]:checked').val();`,
where 'test' is the name of your radio inputs.

Take a look at this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e90t3y9z/)**.

**EDIT**

If you want to detect label clicks as well, a second event handler needs to be added:

```
$('label').click(function() {
       labelID = $(this).attr('for');
       $('#'+labelID).trigger('mousedown');
});
```

Check the updated **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lrf8xjo/1/)**.

Comment: good idea, but unfortunately it doesnt work if labels used, so I need capture label clicks separately.   https://jsfiddle.net/1Lrf8xjo/  anyway, in some cases this idea is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could also keep a copy of the checked value in a data attribute which you then update accordingly in the click handler:

```js
$('input[name=test]').click(function(){
    var previous = $('input[name=test][data-checked=true]')[0];
    console.log(`previous: ${previous.id}`);
    console.log(`this: ${this.id}`);
    
    // the button was already checked so nothing needs to happen
    if (this.id === previous.id) {
      return;
    }
    
    // update data-checked: add attribute to the current button, remove for the rest
    $(this).attr('data-checked', 'true');
    $('input[name=test]:not(:checked)').removeAttr('data-checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1" type='radio' name='test' value='First' checked data-checked='true'>
<label for="test1">First</label><br>

<input id='test2' type='radio' name='test' value='Second'>
<label for="test2">Second</label><br>

<input id='test3' type='radio' name='test' value='Third'>
<label for="test3">Third</label><br>
```